# Ttrying to capture price from amazon based on xpath but if else statement is not working correctly

Tags: python, web-scraping, xpath, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to capture price from amazon based on xpath but if else statement is not working correctly - can someone please help to solve the issue? if 1st xpath didn't find the eliment then it will find through 2nd xpath

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import etree
import requests

HEADERS = ({'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:94.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/94.0','Accept-Language': 'en-US, en;q=0.5'})
    
URL= "https://www.amazon.in/dp/B099Z83VRC"
webpage = requests.get(URL, headers=HEADERS)
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage.content, "lxml")
dom = etree.HTML(str(soup))

Price = dom.xpath('//div[@id="apex_desktop"]/div/div/span/span/text()')[0]
if Price == AttributeError:
    Price = dom.xpath('//div[@id="apex_desktop"]/div/div/table//tr[2]/td[2]/span/span[1]/text()')[0]
else:
    Price = "No data"

Price
```

Comment: didn't understand why people are marking negative mark - I'm new to coding don't understand what is the mistake (: (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use try..except block if it throws error for the first `xpath` it will go except block and try with second one.

```
try:
  Price = dom.xpath('//div[@id="apex_desktop"]/div/div/span/span/text()')[0]
except:
  Price = dom.xpath('//div[@id="apex_desktop"]/div/div/table//tr[2]/td[2]/span/span[1]/text()')[0]
  print(Price)
```